# Looking for a principled/systematic procedure for discarding features

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, covariance, matrix

I have a collection of $M_i \times N$ matrices $X_i$ whose rows
are (raw) feature vectors (from a common $N$-dimensional feature space).

MATLAB reports that most of the covariance matrices $C_i :=
\mathrm{cov}(X_i)$ obtained from these matrices
are "ill-conditioned"<sup>1</sup>.

I would like to find a subset $J$ of the set of columns/features
so that

1. the submatrices $X_i^{\prime}$ obtained by discarding the
    columns<sup>2</sup> in $J$ from the original matrices $X_i$ are such that their
    covariance matrices $C_i^{\prime} :=
        \mathrm{cov}(X_i^{\prime})$ are all "well-conditioned" (i.e. not "ill-conditioned according to MATLAB");
2. the set $J$ is as small as possible<sup>3</sup>.

I'm looking for a principled/systematic (and, of course, tractable!) procedure for computing the subset $J$.

Note: I'm particularly interested in procedures that are
designed/optimized to find a single common subset $J$ of columns to be discarded from *all* the members of a collection of $M_i \times N$ matrices.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>This is not terribly surprising for a number of
reasons, including (a) this is raw data as it comes out of the
instruments, and the features vary greatly in the quality of the
data that can be collected for them; and (b) the set of features
includes several clusters of closely related features, and I
expect that some features in each of these clusters are almost
entirely redundant.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>I know that with principal component
analysis (PCA) one can "reduce the *dimensionality* of the data",
but at this stage I'm not interested in dimension reduction per
se: I want to eliminate whole features.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup>I realize that there is no objective "bright
line" separating "ill-conditioned" from "well-conditioned", and
therefore that MATLAB's classification of matrices as ill
conditioned or not is ultimately arbitrary, but for now I'm
content with going by MATLAB's criterion, warts and all.</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup>I imagine, however, that most
approaches to this sort of problem are designed to work on a
single matrix at a time.  In this case, I'd compute $J$ as the union of
the subsets $J_i$ obtained by applying the procedure separately
to each matrix $X_i$.</sub>